# Fastest way to redirect dead URLs to home page

Tags: apache, wordpress, redirects, 301-redirect

A client of mine scrapped his entire wordpress site of many years for a custom CMS. The URL structures both use the `/<post_title>` format, so a pattern based .htaccess rule is out of the picture for saving the old urls. The old site is effectively dead, but I'd hate to let all of those thousands of backlinks simply die a 404 death.

Is there a faster way than listing *each* url in a .htaccess directive to redirect 1000s of urls to the home page? (Faster as in load speed, not programming efficiency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom 404 page you could check the structure of the URL and 301-redirect if it looks good - or preferably look it up against a known list of previous Wordpress URLs.

At least this way you are only doing the lookup/redirect if the page doesn't exist.

If you are doing 1000s of redirects with Apache, it will be more efficient/faster to do this in your server config (vhost) files. 
Ref: [Move .htaccess content into vhost, for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085222/move-htaccess-content-into-vhost-for-performance)

**EDIT:** I expect you've considered this already, but the thought was beginning to nag... do these missing pages have equivalent new URLs? Although a lot more work, it will obviously be many(*N) times better (for SEO and users) to redirect to the new URL if possible.

<sup>(Where N is a sufficiently large arbitrary number.)</sup>

Comment: That's a great idea. I didn't even think of capturing the 404 and only doing the url match then. I'll need to prevent the actual 404 header, but this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: If you are using something like PHP's `header` function then simply stating an alternative `Location` header should be sufficient to replace the current 404. eg. `header('Location: ...',true,301)`

Comment: Ideally these would all go to a new URL in a subdirectory where I set up a new WordPress install with updated permalinks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about adding a string to the new URL's and then do a regex in Apache config to 301 redirect all URL's that *don't* match the string? You should certainly do 301 redirects to retain the value of the backlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ErrorDocument 404 /404.php" to the .htaccess file and setup a php redirect on 404.php.